# Pass JWT Token in Each API Request

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, token

Hello I am working with JWT Token, and I'm testing API using postman, when perform operation using Postman I set bearer header in Header of postman, it works fine with Postman,
But what if I don't want to set it In postman header and pass it from Controller?
Any Solution Will Helpful,
Here is my code,

Controller,

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
      $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
      $token = auth()->attempt( $credentials);
      return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }
    
    public function me()
    {
      $user =$this->getAuthenticatedUser();
      return response()->json(array($user));
    }

  
   
    protected function createNewToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 1200,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
   
    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {
                if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                    return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
                }

            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
                    return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
                    return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
                    return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    } 




Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'login'])->name('apisignin');
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'jwt.verify',
    'prefix' => 'auth',
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('getauth', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser'])->name('getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::post('userProfile', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'userProfile']);
    Route::post('me', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'me']);
    Route::post('authheader', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'authHeader']);
    Route::post('userupdate', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'userUpdate']);
    Route::post('refresh', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::post('getAuthenticatedUser', [App\Http\Controllers\NewController::class, 'getAuthenticatedUser']);
}); 




public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: This will depend on the technology you're using to perform the requests. The Axios library allows you to set [default headers](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults) for example.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you need to make an API request from your controller.

In order to put a token there, just use `withToken($token)` method on `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` facade:

```
Http::withToken($token)->get($url, $parameters)
```

Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#bearer-tokens

Comment: Basically I want to set it for every API Request

Comment: You should have some sort of a class for making the API requests. I usually create a method request($params, $method = 'get') where I prepare all necessary data for typical requests.

Comment: Yep, Got It, Thank you!